# how to list data types from a document in couchdb

Tags: list, curl, types, couchdb, show

Is there any opprtunity to list all data types of a document in couchdb like string, object,integer ?

I'm using only curl with a Windows machine.

Comment: Using purely CURL?  Could you use design documents?

Comment: @Relaxo can you provide more information about why you want to list all data types?  Is this a one off operation, or  something that will be regularly repeated?  If regular, how frequently?  How big is your dataset?

Comment: @Mark Yes I'm using purely CURL and nothing else.

Comment: @ Chris Snow. It is a only a one off operation. I think it is possible to show data types of a document, but i don't know how i can do this. I think only with curl it is not possible. Do you know how can I list my datatypes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you desire to use purely CURL on the client side you will need to create a design document to answer your query.  The design document would have the following mapping function:

```
function(doc) {
    function obj_to_types( obj ){
        var types = {};
        Object.keys( obj ).forEach( function( k ) {
            var prop = obj[k];
            var type = typeof prop;
            var typeValue;
            if( type == "object" ){
                typeValue = obj_to_types( prop );
            }else{
                typeValue = type;
            }
            types[k] =typeValue;
        });
        return types;
    }
    emit(doc.id, obj_to_types( doc ));
}
```

This will produce output for each document such as:

```
{
_id: "string",
_rev: "string",
format: {
  0: "number",
  1: "number",
  2: "number"},
etc: "string"
}
```

Comment: thanks for your ansewr Mark. How can I transform my normal documents in design documents ? 

And if i not desire to use only Curl, is there a way to show data types ? (normal document)

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comments earlier.  I'm not entirely sure what you are asking for in regards to transforming documents, however you can't modify documents in place with a design document.  Beyond authorization, Couch doesn't care which HTTP client you choose to use.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB is using JSON, and JSON does have a limited set of datatypes, described here: http://json.org/

Any higher level datatype like "DateTime" or such, are a matter of format and not standardized.

Comment: I know that JSON has data types like string, array, object..... But i want to know is there any way to show data types with a command ?

Comment: Please define what you mean with "data types".